# php array of arrays remove array containing matching collection of values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4937
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4937
        [1] => 4941
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4937
        [1] => 5610
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4937
        [1] => 5610
        [2] => 4943
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 108
    )

)
```

Each array is a list of categories followed by its sub categories and sub sub categories. I want to show only original patterns of numbers. so I want to remove array 2 because that pattern of numbers already exists in array 3, but I want keep array 1 because the number that follows 4937 is different to array 3. The end result should be this,

```
Array
(

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4937
        [1] => 4941
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4937
        [1] => 5610
        [2] => 4943
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 108
    )

)
```

Comment: what have you tried? Can you show us (code) where you run in to trouble?

Comment: What if the last array contained `4943` instead of `108`. What should the behavior be? Should that array be removed?

Comment: The original arrays are made from all the categories each item belongs to, I have then requested all the ancestors to each id and added them to the array, so the last array can not contain only 4943     ``` foreach ($product_cat as $cat ) {
  $simple_cats[] = array ( 
    'parent_id' => $cat->parent,
    'id' => $cat->term_id, 
    'acestors' => get_ancestors( $cat->term_id, 'product_cat' )
  );
}

foreach ($simple_cats as &$cat ) {
  $cat['ids'] = array_reverse( $cat['acestors'] );
  array_push($cat['ids'], $cat['id']);
  $cat_ids[] = $cat['ids'];

} ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have multiple parents for child categories, try this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
    end($array[$i-1]);
    $k = key($array[$i-1]);
    if ($array[$i-1][$k] == $array[$i][$k]) {
        unset($array[$i-1]);
    }
}
$array = array_values($array); // reindex array if you need
```